# I dont understand what is wrong with my humanoid code?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

```lua
local sinkpart = script.Parent

local function sink(otherpart)
    print("kill part touched")
    local people = otherpart.Parent
    local humanoid = people:FindFirstChild("humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end

sinkpart.Touched:Connect(sink)
```

when i touced the part, the part doesnt kill the character can anyone explain the problem

I want it to kill who ever touches it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do not post images of code, as no one can copy/paste that to give your code a run. Edit the question and use the `{}` icon to paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be due to trying to find "humanoid" as a child of `people`, assuming otherPart.parent will be a player's character. Accessing children by name in Roblox is case-sensitive, so try using "Humanoid" instead, like this:

```lua
local sinkpart = script.Parent

local function sink(otherpart)
    print("kill part touched")
    local people = otherpart.Parent
    local humanoid = people:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end

sinkpart.Touched:Connect(sink)
```